# Letting users define sender of an email

Tags: php, email, web

a client asked me about a little form for his website, from which it would be possible to mail the URL to someone. Something like "Hey check this out".

Since he was not happy with `mailto:`, I want to use PHP `mail()` function, but i wonder if it is smart to let users define a sender of the email. I am worried about the form being abused for spam/phishing.

Is that a reason to worry? Is it even legal?

Comment: You should either have it give them a basic email like you stated (mailto:) or send from the domain of the website, not the user's email address

Comment: Sounds super risky to me. What didn't the client like about mailto?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. The "legal" part of it kicks in when somebody enters someone's email address without their consent, and if it's an email address of a person who has nothing to do with that person, nor doesn't know that person. If someone would do that here in Canada, they'd be hit by the [**Canadian anti-spam law**](http://fightspam.gc.ca/) faster than you can say "hey, spam!". You'd need to use a list of existing email addresses in a text file or DB to see if the receiver's email is in there and agreed to be in it. You stand at being blacklisted if someone marks it as spam &/or phishing.

Comment: @mopo922 not everyone uses email clients, so i guess he thinks when someone sees MS Outlook (which he never uses) pop up he just automaticaly closes it, and now I'm not even sure what happens when you dont have any client at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's legal to send e-mail. It's not legal (everywhere) to send spam. But you are just providing a share link, not a relay server, so I wouldn't worry about that. If you limit the amount of control over the content of the message, and limit the number of people to send it to, it won't be too interesting for spammers.

Letting the user choose a sender is not a very good idea. Some mail relay servers check if the originating server is allowed to send e-mails for the domain specified in the address, so the mails might never arrive. You can safely set the sender *name*, though.

Apart from that, if the receivers of the message consider it as spam and report it, your domain might become blacklisted, and your mails will be sent to junk mail in many cases, so you want to make sure no (or little) spam is sent through your form.

Those bots try every form automatically just to see what happens, so you'll need to make some effort. You could add a captcha, which is an obstacle for humans too, although [Google is going to put an end to that](http://www.theverge.com/2014/12/3/7325925/google-is-killing-captcha-as-we-know-it). Or you could protect it through other means, like a honeypot. Maybe you can just generate the form through JavaScript, which is a big obstacle for most spam bots.

Comment: *"It's not legal (everywhere) to send spam."* - [**Especially in Canada**](http://fightspam.gc.ca/) ;)

Comment: thank you very much for those suggestions, that was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `From` on an email in php `mail` isn't the cause for concern. The problem is that you'll be sending emails from your server. The mail headers will have your server information embedded - so any issues will tie back to you.

As long as you can safeguard your own server from allowing these spam/phishing attacks, then there's nothing wrong with it.

Just limit the number of people this `mail` function can send to - and make sure it can't be called multiple times in succession -- like with a script.

This way, the spammers wouldn't benefit from using your page to try to send spam. They'll go elsewhere.

There's much more to do to work with sending email, but this will at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it legal" depends upon the country you are in.

I don't think you need to worry about spam if you set up a login.

Or you could limit the number of emails by IP address.  This can be spoofed, however, so it may not be the best option.

There are other control options you could do; limit number of emails by User Agent/IP combination, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the reasons pointed out by others who have answered this question, I would advise against doing this because these messages will likely be marked as spam by spam filters, due to SPF and DMARC records.

For example, is someone sends a message through your system from a yahoo.com address, most spam filters will treat the message as spam, because os Yahoo's DMARC record, which  basically says, 'any message sent from a yahoo.com email address that did not originate from a mail server on yahoo's network is spam'.  See https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN24016.html?impressions=true for more info.